# Ruby Encoding from Previous Hex Encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, hex

I have a situation where a `Nokogiri` result has `hex` encoding into my results.  The problem is where the actual encoding of the result is `UTF-8`, but contains hex characters:

```
Best 100+ Fishing Pictures | Download Free Images on Unsplash
https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fs%2Fphotos%2Ffishing&rut=d1dd8233a6ad628121fa36d8d5a51be0b6fb0eda75e234d5036bf7b49efcf25b
current encoding: UTF-8

Fish Images | Free Vectors, Stock Photos & PSD
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.com%2Ffree%2Dphotos%2Dvectors%2Ffish&rut=f68a290a96893c63f8849bc9e89152d97a632d7a95bbf5d0ca2e939b378fff68
current encoding: UTF-8

How to Use Fish vs. fishes Correctly
https%3A%2F%2Fgrammarist.com%2Fusage%2Ffish%2Dfishes%2F&rut=e0897e219c9b0b125a1442b59e36c49753417a1b7812ae9d3ab0bc3179ffe6b5
current encoding: UTF-8
```

The URLs are technically encoded as `UTF-8`, but have hex characters.  I haven't found anything that has seen them as hex to translate to `UTF-8`, so I'm lost as to how to recognize those character groupings for translation.  Outside of writing a complex method that **might** work, I thought I would see if there's a force-recognition of the original string to be then translated using `force_encode` or something of that sort.

Anybody have any advice how to accomplish this?  Any insight appreciated.  I'd rather avoid having to hand-code these characters into a method.

**Update**:
`CGI::unescapeHTML(<string>]` isn't working:

```
irb(main):024:0> a
=> "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.com%2Ffree%2Dphotos%2Dvectors%2Ffish&rut=f68a290a96893c63f8849bc9e89152d97a632d7a95bbf5d0ca2e939b378fff68"
irb(main):025:0> CGI::unescapeHTML(a)
=> "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.com%2Ffree%2Dphotos%2Dvectors%2Ffish&rut=f68a290a96893c63f8849bc9e89152d97a632d7a95bbf5d0ca2e939b378fff68"
irb(main):026:0> CGI::unescapeHTML(a) == a
=> true
```

Comment: Does https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-unescape this help at all?

Comment: No.  Updated the OP.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided a code snippet which reproduces the problem rather than just the output of your script.

Comment: @voxobscuro Third line of the Update.  Otherwise I cannot find anything that works.  So nothing to really post.

Comment: The string is not HTML-escaped, it is URI-escaped. Try the method linked in [Jad's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562304/ruby-encoding-from-previous-hex-encoding#comment126479724_71562304). Still, you are fixing symptoms, not the root cause. You need to figure out why the string is wrongly escaped in the first place, not how to undo something that should never have been done in the first place.

Comment: Ya the URL was provided that way in a scrape.  But `CGI::unescape(<string>)` worked.  Because it was provided as `HTML`, that's why I tried that option.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give the source for your "encoding of the result is UTF-8, but contains hex characters" in the original question. I don't think I understand that question.

In your update, you used the incorrect method. `unescapeHTML` is for resolving HTML entities:

```
irb(main):010:0> CGI.escapeHTML '<'
=> "&lt;"
irb(main):012:0> CGI.unescapeHTML '&lt;'
=> "<"
```

The method you need to use is for decoding URL sequences:

```
irb(main):017:0> encoded_url = "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.com%2Ffree%2Dphotos%2Dvectors%2Ffish&rut=f68a290a96893c63f8849bc9e89152d97a632d7a95bbf5d0ca2e939b378fff68"
=> "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.com%2Ffree%2Dphotos%2Dvectors%2Ffish&rut=f68a290a96893c63f8849bc9e89152d97a632d7a95bbf5d0ca2e939b378fff68"
irb(main):018:0> CGI.unescape encoded_url
=> "https://www.freepik.com/free-photos-vectors/fish&rut=f68a290a96893c63f8849bc9e89152d97a632d7a95bbf5d0ca2e939b378fff68"
```

If that doesn't solve your actual problem, I'm happy to revise given a more debuggable source code in the question.

Comment: Was solved using `CGI.unescape`, correct.  I tried `CGI.unescapeHTML`, which was incorrect.